# How to install VLC 2.1 on Linux Mint 17?

Tags: linux-mint, vlc-media-player, apt

I've tried this after running the following commands on my Linux Mint 17 box:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-pulse
```

VLC version "2.0.6 Twoflower" installs instead of 2.1.x.

`apt-cache policy vlc` produces the following output:

```
vlc:
  Installed: 1:2.0.6-dmo3
  Candidate: 1:2.0.6-dmo3
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.0.6-dmo3 0
        500 http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ wheezy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.1.4+git20150212+r54593+19+11~ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
     2.1.4-0ubuntu14.04.1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe i386 Packages
     2.1.2-2build2 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe i386 Packages
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I renamed `/etc/apt` to `/etc/apt-old` and copied `/etc/apt` from a live CD. This fixed the issue.